# Can I limit the drawing size of icons when my map is scaled?

Tags: carto

I have created some custom icons that I'm using to represent points on my map. For the case in point, I'm using a skyscraper icon to indicate construction projects underway. It looks cool at certain scales, but when I zoom out farther to get the big picture, my icons just overlap into a blobby mess and all meaning is lost. So, is there a way to limit the scaling at a certain point so that when I zoom out farther than, say, a 15 zoom, my icons will no longer scale any larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set marker width in the CartoCSS according to the zoom level - no need to use javascript to change the layer on the fly.

See https://nyc.cartodb.com/viz/87644af8-9e11-11e3-a723-0ed66c7bc7f3/map for example. As you zoom in and out the icon size changes.

The CartoCSS for it is:

```
#nyc_crime_map {
   marker-width: 2;
   marker-opacity: 0.9;
   marker-allow-overlap: true;
   marker-placement: point;
   marker-type: ellipse;
   marker-line-width: 0;
   marker-line-color: #FFF;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
}
#nyc_crime_map [zoom > 11] {
   marker-width: 3;
}
#nyc_crime_map [zoom > 12] {
   marker-width: 5;
}
#nyc_crime_map [zoom > 13] {
   marker-width: 7;
   marker-line-width: 0.5;
}
#nyc_crime_map [zoom > 15] {
   marker-width: 9;
   marker-line-width: 0.5;
}
#nyc_crime_map [zoom > 17] {
   marker-width: 12;
   marker-line-width: 1;
}

#nyc_crime_map[cr="GRAND LARCENY"] {
   marker-fill: #A6CEE3;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="ROBBERY"] {
   marker-fill: #1F78B4;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="FELONY ASSAULT"] {
   marker-fill: #B2DF8A;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="BURGLARY"] {
   marker-fill: #33A02C;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="GRAND LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE"] {
   marker-fill: #FB9A99;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="RAPE"] {
   marker-fill: #E31A1C;
}
#nyc_crime_map[cr="MURDER"] {
   marker-fill: #FDBF6F;
}
```

This one scales slowly, you don't need to adjust as much on the zoom levels. And you could change from the icon to just a colored marker if you want.

The size that you set is in pixel, so to give the appearance of it 'not scaling' you have to lower the maker-width at various steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Maps, you could use a map event listener on the "zoom_changed" event that would change the CartoCSS style.

```
cartodb.createLayer(
  map,
  'http://examples.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/european_countries_e/viz.json',   
  function(layer) {
    layer.createSubLayer({
    sql: 'SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places_simple',
    cartocss: '#layer { marker-width: 5; }'
  });
}).addTo(map);

var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom_level map.getZoom();
  if (zoom_level > 15){
    sublayer.set({'cartocss': '#layer {marker-width: 3 }' }) 
  }
  else { 
    sublayer.set({'cartocss': '#layer {marker-width: 8 }' }) 
  }
});
```

Here's more information that may help you get started if you needed something a bit more advanced, or information on creating the Google Map.

[Google Maps Event Listeners API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

[CartoDB.js API Reference](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#cartodblayer)

[CartoCSS Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/carto/api/2.1.0/#marker-width)